# touchpad does not work on Asus X450L

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, touchpad

I resently installed ubuntu 14.04 on my ASUS X450L.
It runs quite statisfactory, only the touchpad of the laptop does not function.
Is there any solution for this?

The bios setting is 'enabled'

Answer (score 2):

**The only solution right now is to use an external mouse.** (May be outdated?)

I currently have the same problem with my Asus X450CC, and sadly have not been able to find a solution yet.

Other users with X550CA / X550LC seem to have the same problem too.

Someone filed
[launchpad bug 1314198: [Asus X550LC] Touchpad not Recognized in ubuntu 14.04 Edi](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1314198),
and you can subscribe to it to be notified when something new on this issue is posted.

The interesting comment on the bug is [#31](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1314198/comments/31):

> [...]
>   In the mean time, I can provide a workaround which should make the
>   touchpad work in ps/2 mouse emulation mode (so no 2 finger scrolling,
>   etc.), and stop it from interfering with an external mouse.
>
> Sounds good? Try booting with "psmouse.proto=bare" on the kernel
>   cmdline.
>
> See: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters for how to
>   add a parameter to the kernel commandline.

Comment: I've made a blog post to summarize everything I know on this subject: [Asus touchpad not detected under Ubuntu Linux](http://cksum.blogspot.com/2014/06/asus-touchpad-not-detected-under-ubuntu.html). This bug affects at least Asus X450CC, X550CA, X550LB, X550LC, X550LD, X750LB

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading the bios solved the problem for me.

Comment: It's short, but a pretty useful and valid answer.

Comment: It is helpful, but could be better. It would be helpful to know how I can do this? Could you expand please?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @xiaodongjie It was **exactly my point** that the post clearly answers the question. It provides a new, alternative solution, much better than existing solutions. It is short because it basically anounces that a standard update fixed the problem. There is nothing to describe about the bios update, that all depends on the speciffic computer. But to know that it helps to do an update, that is **really useful**.

Comment: @Mehran Can you add which computer model you used?

Answer (score 1):

Updating the Bios did the trick.

Just download the update from the [ASUS support website](http://support.asus.com/download/ModelList.aspx?SLanguage=en&keyword=x450L&type=1) and put it in a pendrive. Boot into Bios, go to advanced and open the Flash Utility.

Answer (score -1):

I have same model and was having some issues on scroll function.
To me works fine the following solution:
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1182816#c9

Comment: Hi Eduardo, while this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. 
Please take a look here: [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://askubuntu.com/help/deleted-answers). Please edit your answer.

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your material...