# Touchpad not working in Asus X-450L

Tags: laptop, touchpad, asus

I am using Ubuntu-14.04 LTS with latest 4.0 kernel. But still it's not working with my touchpad driver. I haven't left no stone unturned to make it supportable for my Ubuntu. Now I am really disgusted at this issue. Have you any working fix?

Be noted, it's not only my issue. Search on google and you will find many people getting same issues.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `dmesg | grep pnp` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and after looking around a lot I found that updating the BIOS it works, and, if I am not mistaken the sound bottons will work too.

You need to update it to the 208, and it will work, dual finger scroll and everything, just one problem, if the laptop go suspended you will need to reboot to use it again.

Go to the end of this page

[touchpad does not work on Asus X450L](https://askubuntu.com/questions/460402/touchpad-does-not-work-on-asus-x450l)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)**  Please don't answer a duplicate question with a copy of the duplicate answer.  Just press "flag" and flag it as a duplicate.  You will get more reputation from that then what you're trying to do now...